# update abc.js file content using nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

```
I have on abc.js file in node side.Having below content:
```

abc.js

```
"use strict";
// Test specific configuration
// ===========================
module.exports = {
     port: process.env.PORT || 8101,
     api:{xyz:"old"}
}



while using below code to update api->xyz value :
```

nodetest.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = './abc.js';
var file = require(fileName);

file.api.xyz= "new";

fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file, null, 2), function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
  console.log('writing to ' + fileName);
});

I am getting below output in abc.js

{
  "port": 8101,
  "api":{"xyz":"new"}
}
```

In overwritten abc.js, "use strict","module.exports" and comments are missing.So how can I keep all content of abc.js file with same format and only with the changed value of "xyz" value.

desired output should be:

abc.js

```
"use strict";
// Test specific configuration
// ===========================
module.exports = {
     port: process.env.PORT || 8101,
     api:{xyz:"new"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to manually add them back in, since when you `require` them, the only thing you are importing into your file is the export (in this case, the object you are updating.)

```
const output = `
"use strict";
// Test specific configuration
// ===========================
${JSON.stringify(file)}
`
fs.writeFile(fileName, output, ...
```

Otherwise, you'd have to use `fs.readFile`, update the resulting string, and then write it.